# XML data is not display in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, xml

I created a project to display XML Data on html page. The project is successfully display data in other browsers. But does not display in Internet explore. I have no idea about how to fix the issue. Please help.

here is the link.

https://relienztk.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Just enclose the whole XML in a `<PRE>...</PRE>` replacing all `&` with `&amp;` and all `<` with `&lt;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template literals doesn't support for IE browsers. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).